# ASP.NET Core: Fetch image from external site and save on Server

Tags: image, asp.net-core, download, upload

I want to fetch an image from an external site and save it on the web application´s server.
My current code downloads the file, but it won't open because of wrong format, it says.

```
private Uri _uri;
private HttpClient _client;

[HttpPost]
public async Task WmsExport(ExportImagePostData postData)
{            
   try
   {
      PrepareUri(postData);
      ValidateUrl(postData);
      PrepareRequest(postData);
      await FetchImageAndSave_async(postData);
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
       HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 408;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       var statusCode = 500;                
       HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
        _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
    }            
 }

 private void PrepareRequest(ExportImagePostData postData)
 {
    _client = _customClientFactory.CreateHttpClient();
    _client.BaseAddress = _uri;
    _client.CopyRequestHeaders(HttpContext);
    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "image/png");
 }

 public async Task FetchImageAndSave_async(ExportImagePostData postData)
 {        
    using (var contentStream = await _client.GetStreamAsync(_client.BaseAddress.OriginalString))
    {
       await SaveImageOnServer_async(postData, contentStream);
    }
 }

 private async Task SaveImageOnServer_async(ExportImagePostData postData, Stream downloadStream)
 {
     var filename = "wmsexp" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmm") + "." + postData.ImageType;
     var directory = "wwwroot/Images/uploads/";
     var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), directory, filename);

     using (var outStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 1048576, true))
     {            
         await downloadStream.CopyToAsync(outStream);                
     }
 }
```

Here is how the images look like in my folder, when I try to open them:
[image]

****SOLVED** **

I got help from Roman Marusyk, here on Stack Overflow. Thanks Roman! If you write an answer I be happy to set it as the answer!
 The issue seem to have been that I added wrong HTTP-headers, and that some of my paths to the images where incorrect.

Comment: show us where is the problem, exception message

Comment: There is no exception message. It downloads the images to my directory, but I can't open the images because it says : "It looks like we don't support this file format".

Comment: What format should be?

Comment: When I test the code I use "image/png".

Comment: Did you try other images? Are U sure that `contentStream` contains an image?

Comment: Yeah, I tried jpeg

Comment: It seems like the GetStreamAsync makes an application/xml call to the external site, despite that I configured the httpClient Accept header to be image/*

Comment: It seems that `contentStream` doesn't contains any images. Try to download image by this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvzM0.png, it should works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202654/discussion-between-olof84-and-roman-marusyk).